# How to use a password manager to provide personal access token to git push/pull

Tags: bash, git, shell, security, gitlab

### Context

Assuming that:

- I have a repository on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) and I have already cloned it on my machine.
- I have a GitLab token allowing me to push from and pull to this repository.
- This token is already saved into my [Bitwarden](https://vault.bitwarden.com/) vault.
- Thanks to the [Bitwarden CLI](https://bitwarden.com/help/article/cli/), I can authenticate/lock/unlock my vault programmatically.

### Question

Is there a way to programmatically chain/pipe the GitLab token fetched on the fly by Bitwarden to the git push and pull commands in order to authenticate/authorize these operations?

### Investigations

I heard about the following solutions to workaround the issue but they do not comply with the security rules I need to face: I can't store any secret in plain text on disk.

- The GitLab token can be put in git credentials helper.store file. Here the GitLab token needs to be stored in plain text in the store file.
- The git remote URLs can be modified to include the credentials in them. Here the GitLab token needs to be stored in plain text in git remote URLs.

### Notes

- I can't use SSH keys, I need to stay on the HTTPS protocol.
- The git version I target is the one proposed from official Ubuntu packages (`2.17.1` at the time of writing).

Comment: Have you looked at the [Custom Helpers](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_custom_helpers) section of the `gitcredentials` documentation? That seems to have pretty much everything you need.

Comment: Hey @larsks, Nop, I didn't have a look but now that I read it (along with the code in AZMCode/git-credential-bw, suggested by @VonC), this seems to be perfect for my use case. I now need to tackle the implementation details, I will go back here to give a feedback.

Comment: @larsks The version of git I use is `2.17.1`, for which the documentation does not have the `CUSTOM HELPERS` section with the same content (it is nearly empty for the 2.13.7). Do you know if it is newly introduced feature or was it only the documentation was updated recently?

Comment: I'm not sure when the documentation changed. You may want to upgrade your Git; the current version is 2.29.2.

Comment: @HadrienTOMA I don(t think you need to upgrade: any `git-credential-xxx` executable would still be considered as a custom helper, even  in 2.17.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the custom Git credential helper [`AZMCode/git-credential-bw`](https://github.com/AZMCode/git-credential-bw) does what you need.

> This is a project to integrate the Bitwarden CLI with Git so as to avoid inconveniences in having to retype a password multiple times, or manage multiple Bitwarden credentials for different sites.

```
git config credential.helper bw
```

Comment: This seems interesting, I need something much simpler but I think I will be able to extract the parts I want. Thank you very much, I will go back with my progress on it here.